# Move files & folders and Symlink

Tags: shell-script, files, symlink, mv, ln

I am looking for a way to exclude some files/folder and mass move files/folders with spaces and special characters from source to destination and then symlink after move completes. So far I have something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
prev_dir=/test
new_dir=/dirtest2
cd $prev_dir
for i in `cat /scripts/files2move.txt`
   do
   sed -i 's/\r$//' $i 
   echo $i
   cd $prev_dir
   mv $i $new_dir && ln -s $new_dir $prev_dir
   ln -s $i $new_dir $prev_dir
done
```

Comment: First thing: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618) Second first thing: [Why you don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of what you want your script to do. There is a few things that I don't fully follow in your code. For example, it looks as if you want to use `sed` to remove a carriage-return character, but it's unclear why this is part of a script that moves files. I'm also not sure about your call to `ln` with three pathname arguments, or why none of your variable expansions are quoted even though you say you work with filenames that has spaces and "special" characters in their names.

Comment: am not saying it does not work with special characters I am saying thats what I want for everyone to keep in mind. The Goal to move files/folders and replace with symlink and to exclude files/folders on a list from this script.